# How to disable Swagger authorization for specific endpoints in dotnet app

Tags: .net, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I have a web api using dotnet core 7. I'm using JWT authentication. I have a controller that is attributed with `Authorize`. This controller's endpoint redirects the client to an external resource (from another API), it is worth noticing that I attributed the endpoint with `AllowAnonymous`.

I also use the standard OpenAPI library for the API spec. The security rules are declared in the following way in `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer",
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Description = "Please enter token",
            Name = "Authorization",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
            BearerFormat = "JWT",
            Scheme = "bearer"
        });

    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "Bearer" }
            },
            Array.Empty<string>()
        }
    });
});
```

For some reason, Swagger Client sets the `Authorization` header for the redirected request too. I'm trying to figure out a way to disable this behavior for any resource that is outside of the scope of my application. I saw some examples `IDocumentFilter` but I'm not sure if it's the "correct" way to do it. Is there a way to do it declaratively right in the configuration specified above, by setting some rules for the exclusion? I would appreciate any help, thanks!

I tried creating the `IDocumentFilter`, `IOperationFilter` but the solutions were pretty dirty and I did not achieve the result.

Controller's code:

```cs
using System.Security.Claims;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using SafeShare.DAL;
using SafeShare.DTO;

using File = SafeShare.Models.File;

namespace SafeShare.Controllers;

[Route("api/files")]
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
public class FilesController : ControllerBase
{
    private const int PresignedRequestDurationSeconds = 60 * 60; // 1 hour
    private readonly BlobRepository _blobRepository;
    private readonly string _bucketName;
    private readonly IFilesRepository _filesRepository;

    public FilesController(
        BlobRepository blobRepository,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        IFilesRepository filesRepository)
    {
        _filesRepository = filesRepository;
        _bucketName = configuration["MINIO_BUCKET_NAME"]!;
        _blobRepository = blobRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFiles()
    {
        string? userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
        if (userId is null)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        File[] files = await _filesRepository.GetFilesByUserEmail(userId);
        IEnumerable<FileDto> fileDtos = files.Select(file => new FileDto(file));
        return Ok(fileDtos);
    }

    [HttpPost("presigned-url")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreatePresignedPutUrl([FromBody] CreatePresignedPutUrlDto dto)
    {
        string? currentUserEmail = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
        if (currentUserEmail is null)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        File file = await _filesRepository.AddFile(new File
        {
            Name = dto.Name,
            OwnerEmail = currentUserEmail,
            IsOneTimeUse = dto.IsOneTimeUse,
            ExpiresAt = dto.ExpiresAt
        });

        string urlString =
            await _blobRepository.GeneratePresignedPutRequest(
                _bucketName,
                dto.Name,
                file.Id.ToString(),
                PresignedRequestDurationSeconds);

        return Ok(urlString);
    }


    [HttpPost("read/{id}")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreatePresignedGetUrl([FromRoute] string id)
    {
        File? file = await _filesRepository.GetFileById(id);
        if (file is null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        string urlString =
            await _blobRepository.GeneratePresignedGetRequest(_bucketName, id, PresignedRequestDurationSeconds);

        if (file.IsOneTimeUse)
        {
            // TODO clean up the blob storage too
            await _filesRepository.RemoveFile(file);
        }

        return Redirect(urlString);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your controller code?

Comment: Sure, @ShubhamWagh! Updated the question with the information you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add [AllowAnonymous] attr to some actions of your controller

Comment: I did add it, but the Authorization header is still present for all of the requests if a user is authenticated in Swagger Client. But thanks for the idea, I updated the question!